# Command prompt isn't showing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

everyone!
I'm using VS 2010 to write code in C++ and today I encountered a "bug". I opened a console application I've previously written in that same environment with the exact same settings. The program ran successfully

> 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.96
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

but sadly, no command prompt window opened.
To clarify - the main function ends with

> system ("PAUSE"); return 0;

Previous runs have always opened the command prompt window and there were no changes to the code or the environment settings.
I opened the .cpp file with the Devcpp environment and it ran as expected, without problems.
Please give me suggestions on what I might be doing wrong!

EDIT -

I tried running this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    return 0;
}
```

with the same result.

Ctrl + F5 runs the program and opens up the prompt, but the regular way doesn't.

Comment: Do you have avast?

Comment: If your program runs without any errors, you should see a message in the "Output" window that looks like: *The program '[32648] myprogram.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)*. If the program exited with a different exit code, you need to dig deeper.

Comment: @n.m. No, I don't.

Comment: @RSahu I am now noticing there is no such line on the "Output" window.

Comment: Not supplying code is one thing you're doing wrong. Hard to debug that which is unseen. Visual Studio and DevCPP use different compilers and different debuggers. Very likely when built under DevCPP, something (and I can't get more specific than that) looks like it's working by dumb bad luck, but Visual Studio handles the code a bit differently and fully exposes the error.

Comment: Off topic: Rather than `system("pause")`, just do a `char junk; std::cin >> junk;` or similar. `system("pause")` is an awesomely heavy weight way to wait for the user to press enter.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't provide code because I'm not sure which part will be useful and I'm not going to post the whole 391 line thing. Also, I wrote it in VS. The Devcpp thing was just to check if it will work.

Comment: @user4581301 Plus, I tried the most basic "Hello world!" program and the result was the same.

Comment: That's problematic, yeah. Step one is put a breakpoint right at the top of the `main` function and rerun the program. See if you even get that far.

Comment: And @n.m.'s comment about Avast is still a valid concern. Check to see if your Antivirus software is blocking execution.

Answer (score -1):

The details you give aren't very precise, could you provide the code? It sounds like the code is not compiling but not running, or you're redirecting the output somewhere. There's an option for "run after compile" you might have turned off.

Try launching your program directly (Ctrl+F5) so VS doesn't redirect the output, or launching it from the command prompt in your "bin" folder. If they work you might have changed something by accident.

To fix you could try:

- Reset VS settings - "Tools -> Import and export settings -> Reset". You'll obviously lose any custom configuration if you did that, but there's an option to save any custom config like fonts and colours that you want to keep (on the same screen select "export").
- Reset project settings - probably easiest to create a new project and copy your code in.

(I'd add this to comments but don't have enough rep).

Comment: And, as you know yourself, this is not an **answer**, and it should have been a comment.

Comment: Ok, so Ctrl+F5 works, but I dont know how to "redirect the output".

Comment: Included a potential fix to my answer. Hope this helps.